# Showing Dialog After Long Process

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the following code, I have a long running process called `GetExcelData`.  When it's complete, I want to show a dialog to save it's contents into a TXT file.

The problem is, when debugging, I get the following error:

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode
>   before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has
>   STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a
>   debugger is attached to the process.

This is my code.  The error occurs on the line that reads `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();`

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("C:\\MyExcelFile.xlsx");

ConsoleApplication2.Program.ExcelData data = ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData(existingFile, _worker);

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
{
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, json);
}
```

I have tried adding the `[STAThread]` attribute to the method I am calling this from but it didn't seem to work.

**Please let me provide more code for additional clarity as to what I am trying to do:**

The following exists in a WPF project which references my Console project:

```
private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set up the BackgroundWorker.
    this._backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    this._backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    this._backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    this._backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=
                              new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this._backgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
    {
        this._backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}

void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the Value porperty when porgress changed.
    this.progressBar1.Value = (double)e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker _worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if (_worker != null)
    {
        FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("C:\\MyExcelFile.xlsx");

        ConsoleApplication2.Program.ExcelData data = ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData(existingFile, _worker);

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, while we're here, if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
Just a little thing that might help :)

Comment: Is this a winform program or a console application?  Your code has indications of both.  Where is the code sample shown being called from?

Comment: To avoid confusion, please explain, your GetExcelData is running in a different thread than the Main thread?

Comment: @Servy Good question.  It is a WPF project that references a Console project.

Comment: @user1477388 And my second question?

Comment: @Steve I have not yet specified any threads; I am simply calling the the method from my Console application from my WPF application.

Comment: @Servy Please see my answer to Steve above which I believe answers your question also.

Comment: @user1477388 So it's running in the UI thread?  If so, it should already be an STA thread.  The error indicates this is a background thread.

Comment: @Servy Sorry for the confusion.  I have added more code which should clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 So you're creating a new background thread to do the work; something you specifically said you *weren't* doing in comments.

Comment: @Servy Sorry as I am new to WPF I mispoke.

Comment: I suggest to add a RunWorkerCompleted event and call the code that show the Dialog in that method.

Comment: @Steve I like that idea but I am not sure how to implement it.  If you can provide any examples while I try to figure it out, that would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: @Servy the OP says the error happens on `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code that interacts with the UI to the same thread that handle your UI elements. The easiest way to do so it through the RunWorkerCompleted event

```
  this._backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                          new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_WorkComplete);

  ....

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker _worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if (_worker != null)
    {
        FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("C:\\MyExcelFile.xlsx");
        ConsoleApplication2.Program.ExcelData data = ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData(existingFile, _worker);

        e.Result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
     }
 }

 private void bw_WorkComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
       string json = e.Result.ToString();
       File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, json);
    }
}
```

In the DoWork method, save the json string in the e.Result property of the DoWorkEventArgs class and retrieve it in the RunWorkerCompleted event from the RunWorkerCOmpletedEventArgs property with the same name.

Comment: How do you recommend handling the `json` variable since that does not exist in the context?

Comment: @user1477388 You set and then read from the `Result` property of the arguments of each event.

Comment: @Servy Thanks to you both for your help!  I have got it working now.  I prefer this solution (`bw_Workcomplete`) because it is simpler than the others in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes as @Servy said. Pass your data around using the Result property.  Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Why?

Basically what happens is that you call `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();` from `bw_DoWork`.  And that's not right. `Dialog` is the UI control and should run from the UI thread and `bw_DoWork` method is executed in a separate thread (which is non-UI).

#### How to fix this?

Move the dialog show code away from the `bw_DoWork` method and pass the needed string instead. So the algorithm would look like

- Click a button or whatever action to show the dialog [UI thread]
- Open dialog  [UI thread]
- Verify you get a valid string from the dialog [UI thread]
- Start background worker and pass a file path string [UI thread]
- Write to file [background worker thread]

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Program.cs` so the declaration of the `Main` method looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that too and it doesn't go away `[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)`